# MySQL synchronization?

Tags: mysql, sql, synchronization, locking, isolation-level

I was always wondering if MySQL queries are synchronized - or whatever you call it. For example:

You read a value using SELECT, then you modify it in your code (let's say, PHP on a webserver) and then you UPDATE the table entry. If two processes do this simultaneously, there will obviously be problems.

How is this prevented?

Comment: Through locking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about transaction isolation levels and locks. This is the related link for mysql: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Comment: You are right, this is the correct way. Not good that all those tutorials never mention the problems with their non-locking read-modify-write-approach. So there really is nothing preventing race conditions in a lot of PHP applications. Madness... D: